# Finding adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X, Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $\tau:Y\to X$ be continuous and $A \in \mathcal B(C(X),C(Y))$ the operator given by $Af:=f\circ \tau$.

> Show that the adjoint operator $A' \in \mathcal B(M(X),M(Y))$ is given by $$(A'\mu)(\Delta)=\mu(\tau^{-1}(\Delta)), \ \ \ \mu \in M(Y),\ \Delta \subseteq X\ \mathrm{Borel\ set}$$

$M(X)$ is the set of all regular complex borel measures on $X$.

Let $1_\Delta$ be the indicator function of $\Delta$

$A'\mu(\Delta)=<1_\Delta,A'\mu>=<A1_\Delta,\mu>=\int A1_\Delta d\mu=\int 1_\Delta \circ \tau d\mu$

Since $(1_\Delta \circ \tau)(\Omega)\subseteq\{0,1\}$, we have $A'\mu(\Delta)=\mu\Big(\{x:(1_\Delta\circ\tau(x))=1\}\Big)=\mu(\tau^{-1}(\Delta))$

> Is this correct? Why does the first equality $A'\mu(\Delta)=<1_\Delta,A'\mu>$ hold? If you know of any better solutions, I would appreciate to see them.